# Loop not giving the required result

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame and in the first column I need to print for whole row the value that if it is greater than the threshold value print yes otherwise no. It is showing only a "No" value. j1 is the dataframe.

```
for(i in nrow(j1)){
  for(j in ncol(j1)){
  if (j1[i,j] > 400){
    print("yes")
  }else{print("No")}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed something in the condition of `for` loop, which is supposed to be as below:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(j1)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(j1)){
  if (j1[i,j] > 400){
    print("yes")
  }else{print("No")}
}
}
```

Note that `nrow(j1)` and `ncol(j1)` are just single values for the dimensions of `j1`, not a vector starting from `1`.

Comment: Cab you elaborate??